# Обратный слеш в json_decode

Tags: php

Есть текст(из БД), который нужно превратить в json. [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6efc172d7e5b5050df1183ac05b4322e873ae435)

```
$text = '[{"val":"4"}]';
$f = json_decode($text);
```

Все получилось, но если в нем встречается обратный слеш `\` то все ломается. [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc38f91392ab53d1c6d60a7983238b82b89e1bf2)

```
$text = '[{"val":"4\4"}]';
$f = json_decode($text);
```

Нашел выход в функции [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php)

Но это не особо подходит, т.к. она удаляет `\`. [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4dba4b0dc6a625c92f82303a1ebbc4d907138cd4)

Есть другой выход с сохранения `\`?

Comment: Это некорректный json, который просто не должен существовать. Откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: @andreymal Почему он не корректный? Так реализовано хранение доп. полей для товара. То есть у каждого товара в бд есть поле field и в нем хранится этот json, `[{"id":тут id доп. поля,"val":"тут любое значение"}, ..]`

Comment: Ну потому что некорректный. Сочетание символов `\4` является синтаксической ошибкой в JSON-строках

Comment: Самое правильное решение вопроса в данном случае — выдать люлей тому, кто делал хранение доп. полей для товара, и заставить его переделать всё в синтаксически корректный JSON. Всё остальное это костыли

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас некорректно закодирован JSON (либо передан с ошибкой).

[По спецификации JSON](http://json.org/) в строке после символа `\` не может стоять число 4. После `\` допустимо использовать только:

- `"` - кавычка, просто экранирование кавычки
- `\` - обратный слеш - экранирование для самого себя для однозначного распознавания символьных последовательностей с особым значением в строках
- `/` - прямой
- `b` - символ `backspace`
- `n` - символ `line feed` (перевод строки)
- `r` - символ `carriage return` (возврат каретки)
- `t` - символ табуляции
- `u` с последующими 4 HEX символами, обозначает соответствующий символ Unicode (этой формой записи допустимо заменить вышеуказанные символы, впрочем)

Так, `\4` это некорректная запись.

Такой JSON не принимают ни парсер PHP, ни проверенный мной парсер в PostgreSQL. Его пытается обработать парсер JS в `firefox`, но не уверен по каким правилам. Cам JSON от этого корректным не станет.

Корректная запись должна быть:

```
[{"val":"4\\4"}]
```

И лучше здесь вам обратиться к источнику вашего JSON с вопросом почему он сформирован некорректно чем пытаться исправлять последствия.

Comment: второй слеш не в ту сторону) то что у вас, можно и без экрана

Comment: ау, опечатка. Спасибо

Comment: А можно пример, когда `\4` может быть корректно? Я попытался написать `\4000` (это же вроде четыре HEX-символа?), но JSON.parse в джаваскрипте всё равно ругается

Comment: Вообще, если я правильно понимаю спецификацию, после \ может стоять один из `"\/bnrtu`, а `4` стоять не может никогда

Comment: хороший вопрос, перечитываю внимательнее, да, `\u` это обязательно должен быть

Answer (score 1):

Спец символы JSON

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```